# android emulator default location is not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, android-studio, react-redux

I have issue shoing Geo location. I think it is not coding problem, as i wrote the code which worked before. It shows no location.

[image]

ANnd then in Location tab, I could see Mountain View

[image]

But i could not see it on my App.The location does not show.
thanks
sal

Comment: The only way I managed to set the location on my emulator after "setting location" in the "Location" tab, was to open google maps on the emulator itself, then go to the current location. Then go back to my app, and walla...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to AVD
Choose your device
Go into settings
Emulated Performance -> Graphics - set to Hardware - GLES 2.0

Comment: Thanks maniak, but Graphics is greyed out

Comment: try another emulator phone who have google play support